# List of files that were NOT changed by a git commit

Tags: git

I know that

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree <sha1>
```

will give me the list of all files included in a given commit, while something like

```
git show --stat --name-only --pretty=format:'' <sha1>
```

will only list the files that were changed by commit `<sha1>`.

How do I get a list of the files that were NOT changed by a given `git` commit? I'm sure it can be done with the commands above plus some `sort` and `diff`, but I would rather do it with `git` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you can do it purely with `git`, at least not with just porcelain commands. I would do this:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree <sha1> | sort > /tmp/allfiles
git show --stat --name-only --pretty=format:'' <sha1> | sort > /tmp/changedfiles
comm -23 /tmp/allfiles /tmp/changedfiles
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do using `*nix` tools alone. Let's see if someone else comes up with a pure `git` solution.